# Como checar os valores vazios de um formulário dinámico?

Tags: jquery, formulário

Como usar Jquery para atacar o atribuno *name* de todos os inputs e verificar se existe valor

**Codigo Atual**

Form:

```
...
<input type="text" name="nome[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="nome[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="nome[]" value="">
...
```

Javascript:

```
...
$('.cadastrar').on("click", function() {
    var nomes = $('input[name="nome[]"]');
    console.log(nomes);
});
...
```

Eu teria que verificar o valor de cada input e se existir algum em branco ele retornaria *false* e um alert..

só que parei na hora de verificar campo a campo. não consegui dar continuidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando usas o jQuery assim: `$('input[name="nome[]"]');` ele vai retornar uma array com todos os inputs que têm esse nome.

Se precisas de saber quais e/ou quantos estão vazios podes usar o `filter()` e usa como retorno uma condição que valide/invalide o valor do input.

Dentro desse `.filter()` ele vai iterar todos os inputs e se o `return` for válido ele mantem esse elemento na array, seão remove-o.

Para saber quantos e quais os inputs vazios:

```
var vazios = $('input[name="nome[]"]').filter(function () {
    return this.value.split(' ').join('') == '';
});
```

depois podes usar o `vazios.length` para saber quantos.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/nzgwgew4/

Answer (score 2):

Use a função **each**

```
$('input[name="nome[]"]').each(function(i, item){
    if(item == "")
        console.log("vazio");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso possa te ajudar.

```
$(' input[type=text]' ).each(
                function(index, element){
                    if(  $(element).val( ).length == 0 ){
                        $(element).focus( )
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            )
```